# width for react-native-material-menu does not work

Tags: react-native

[react-native-material-menu]
I try to customize menu, but style property "width" is not handled - menu still narrow.

```
return(
  <View style = {{
    width: 500
  }}>
  <Menu
    ref = { this.setMenuRef }
    button = {<RoundButton 
      buttonType = "menu"
      navigateTo = "menu"
      menuCall = {this.showMenu}
    style = {{
      width: 500
    }}
    />}
  >
    <MenuItem onPress = {this.hideMenu}>Reports TO DO</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onPress = {this.hideMenu}>Settings TO DO</MenuItem>
    <MenuItem onPress = {this.hideMenu}>Help TO DO</MenuItem>
  </Menu>
</View>
);
```

Can it be customized?

Answer (score 1):

Oops! Looks like you forgot to specify the height of the parent *View*.

Wrap your *Menu* component in a *View* that has a definite *width* and *height*.

The [documentation](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width#fixed-dimensions) clearly says:

> A component can only expand to fill available space if its parent has dimensions greater than 0. If a parent does not have either a fixed width and height or flex, the parent will have dimensions of 0 and the flex children will not be visible.

Solution would be:

```
<View style = {{ width: 500, height: 500 }}>
```

(You can specify the dimensions according to your needs).

**OR**

[Flex](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/height-and-width#flex-dimensions) can also be used.

```
<View style = {{ flex: 1 }}>
```